# Passing NSMutableArray from delegate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, delegates, nsmutablearray

I'm doing an Iphone aplication and in the delegate class i call a method from another class which return a NSMutableArray filled with the information i need:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray initWithObjects:nil] retain];
array = [xml loadXML:@"info.xml"];
```

Now I want to pass this array into the viewController class so i can do things with my mutable array. I do the following:

```
...
[self.window addSubview:viewController.view];
[self.viewController loadLocations:array];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

In delegate, the array is ok, it has the data i want, however, in the viewController class (which is a UIViewController) the array is messed up.

```
-(void)loadLocations:(NSMutableArray*)_array{
    NSLog(@"%f", [[_array objectAtIndex:0] lat]); // This sould be 42.000 but it is 0.00000 and all of the other indexes
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're in trouble right from the beginning:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[array initWithObjects:nil] retain];
```

You're calling "initWithObjects" on "array", but you haven't allocated "array" yet.

You want something like:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:nil];
```

or just :

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Comment: or even simpler `[NSMutableArray new]`

Answer (score 1):

This part is invalid:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[array initWithObjects:nil] retain];
array = [xml loadXML:@"info.xml"];
```

The first line is not used because the second line is setting the array pointer to the result of [xml loadXML:]

I think this should suffice:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[xml loadXML:@"info.xml"]];
```